# JavaScript Asyn Returns Without Waiting For Response

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a JavaScript function which makes an ajax request, and depending on the result either returns `true` or `false`.

The problem is when I am calling the function it is immediately returning, without waiting for the ajax request to fire and really return the right response. How do I handle this?

```
function check_value() {
   //Pseudo code
   ajax('some-url.php', function(response) {
      if(response.success) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   });
}

if(check_value()) {
   alert("true");
} else {
   alert("false");
}
```

See the problem? check_value() is executing and returning immediately, before the AJAX request fires and calls the callback.

Comment: *async* => *not waiting for response* This is basically the definition of the whole concept.

Answer (score 1):

That is the inherent nature of an asynchronous call, you never know when it will be done. So instead create two handlers for success and error:

```
function check_value() {
   //Pseudo code
   ajax('some-url.php', function(response) {
      if(response.success) {
         handleSuccess();
      } else {
         handleError();
      }
   });
}

function handleSuccess() {
    alert('true');
}

function handleError() {
    alert('false');
}
```